# Get checkbox option names when redndering manually

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to get the name of each option associated with a particular checkbox element. For example when I allow django to render the checkbox it produces

```
    <label for="id_amenities_0"><input name="amenities" value="1" id="id_amenities_0" type="checkbox">
 Care Parking</label>
```

Now I'm trying to render the forms manually and I want to find a way of displaying 'Care Parking'. This is what I have done but it doesn't display anything

```
    {% for box in form.amenities %}
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">

        <label class="custom-checkbox" for="id_amenities_{{ forloop.counter0 }}"> {{ box.html_name }}
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_amenities_{{ forloop.counter0 }}"  name="amenities">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is `amenities`? A form field?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes amenities is a form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`choice_label:`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect)

```
{% for box in form.amenities %}
    <label>{{ box.choice_label }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i needed